# Moq Class library

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, moq

I'm trying to find an appropriate way to Moq this, and I'm unsure on how to do it.This is a .Net Standard 2.0 library that must be consumed from .net 4.8, and .net core 3+.

Here is an Example.

```
private ILogService _logService;

public class Logger() :IProjectLogger
{
   _logService = new LogService();
}
```

When testing Logger(), I would like to Moq the ILogService methods. But since this may not always be used with dependency injection, and I don't want the client to have to inject ILogService, I'm stuck on how to moq ILogService methods when testing Logger()

Thanks!

Comment: You really need either dependency injection or service locator.  You need _some_ way to inject your test dependency into your class.  With what you have now, the only option would be to use reflection to set  `_logService`, which is not a practice I would recommend.  (Or you can add property accessors to that field)

Comment: ah ok, so really the only way would be to allow the client to inject ILogService into Logger? Was hoping there was a way where they wouldn't need to register ILogService

Comment: If you want something simple, you can just overload your constructor to take no parameters (instantiate the default) or one that takes your `ILogService` interface.

Comment: Exchange the instance at your _logService field via reflection in your tests?